# Slow mySql update containing Join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have a system that collects data from production reports (CSV files) and puts them into a mySql DB.
I have an header table, that contain the production data of sequential report with same setting, and a table with the single reports, connected to the first one (trfCamRep.hdrId -> trfCamHdr.id).

I have a query to calculate the total report, the dubt and the faulty, and the maxTs. These datas are used in the visualizator.

The query is too slow, it requires 9sec. 
Can you help me to speed up it?

```
SET @maxId:=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM trfCamHdr WHERE srcCod='7');

UPDATE trfCamHdr AS hdr 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT hdrF.id,COUNT(*) AS nTot,
    SUM(IF(res=1,1,0)) AS nWrn,SUM(IF(res=2,1,0)) AS nKO,
        MAX(ts) AS maxTS 
    FROM trfCamHdr AS hdrF 
    JOIN trfCamRep AS repF ON repF.hdrId=hdrF.id 
    WHERE clcEnd=0 AND srcCod='7'
    GROUP BY hdrF.id) AS valT ON valT.id=hdr.id 
SET hdr.clcEnd=IF(hdr.id<@maxId,1,0),
    hdr.nTot=valT.nTot,
    hdr.nWrn=valT.nWrn,
    hdr.nKO=valT.nKO,
    hdr.maxTS=valT.maxTS 
WHERE hdr.id>=0 AND hdr.clcEnd=0 AND hdr.srcCod='7';
```

Note trfCamHdr has these columns:

- id (primary key)
- clcEnd : flag of end calculation (the last remain to 0 because in progress)
- nTot : elements with this header
- nWrn : elements with res = 1
- nKO : elements with res = 2
- maxTs : TS of the last element

trfCamRep has these columns:

- hdrId (refer to id of trfCamHdr)
- res : 0 good, 1 dubt, 2 fault
- ts : report timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I'd take this out:

```
SET @maxId:=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM trfCamHdr WHERE srcCod='7');
```

And any allusions to the MaxId variable, I believe it to be redundant.
Everything you do will be lower than the max id, and it will take time to calculate if its a big table. You are already checking for srcCod = 7, so it isn't necessary.
In fact, it would miss the update on the one with the actual max id, which is not what I believe you want.

Your left join will also update all other rows in the table with NULL, is that what you want? You could switch that to an inner join, and if your rows are already null, they will just get left alone, rather than getting updated with NULL again.

Then you could just switch out this:

```
SET 
    hdr.clcEnd = IF(hdr.id < @maxId, 1, 0),
```

To

```
SET 
    hdr.clcEnd = 1,
```

Here is the rewritten thing, as always, **back your data up** before trying:

```
UPDATE trfCamHdr AS hdr
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        hdrF.id,
            COUNT(*) AS nTot,
            SUM(IF(res = 1, 1, 0)) AS nWrn,
            SUM(IF(res = 2, 1, 0)) AS nKO,
            MAX(ts) AS maxTS
    FROM
        trfCamHdr AS hdrF
    JOIN trfCamRep AS repF ON repF.hdrId = hdrF.id
    WHERE
        clcEnd = 0 AND srcCod = '7'
    GROUP BY hdrF.id) AS valT ON valT.id = hdr.id 
SET 
    hdr.clcEnd = 1,
    hdr.nTot = valT.nTot,
    hdr.nWrn = valT.nWrn,
    hdr.nKO = valT.nKO,
    hdr.maxTS = valT.maxTS
WHERE
    hdr.id >= 0 AND hdr.clcEnd = 0
        AND hdr.srcCod = '7';
```

Comment: Thank you for  the reply. The if is needed in order to update also the last row.

Comment: I want they can see the last row that is update in real time, qhen a new report is created.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I created a KEY on hdrId column and now the query requires 0.062s.